# RSolve fails on a two-equation non-linear system

Tags: equation-solving, version-9, recursion, modeling, difference-equations

I have a system of just two recurrence equations, I need to solve them and so I use `RSolve`:

```
RSolve[{H[n + 1] == (1 + (7 h[n])/10) H[n], 
        h[n + 1] == 1 - (1 + (7 h[n])/10) H[n]}, 
       {H[n], h[n]}, n]
```

But this just returns my code, without any errors:

> ```
> RSolve[{H[1 + n] == (1 + (7 h[n])/10) H[n], 
>         h[1 + n] == 1 - (1 + (7 h[n])/10) H[n]}, 
>        {H[n], h[n]}, n]
> ```

Where am I going wrong? Why am I not even seeing any errors?

Additional Info:

- I am modelling the frequency of two variants, H and h, through discrete time (n)
- Total frequency in the population: h + H = 1
- The two variant's frequencies depend on each other as you can see in the above code

Comment: rewriting your equation shows that there are no Solutions. `RSolve[{H[n + 1] == (1 + (7 h[n])/10) H[n], 
  h[n + 1] + H[n + 1] == 1}, {H[n], h[n]}, n]` gives {}

Comment: Thanks @Max1 hmm... perhaps I could just use RecurrenceTable and get some numerical "solution"

Answer (score 3):

You could also just program iteratively:

```
f[{x_, y_}] := With[{ch = {1, 0.7 x}.{x, y}}, {ch, 1 - ch}]
hdt[p_, n_] := Transpose@NestList[f, {p, 1 - p}, n]
```

If you just want $\{H(n),h(n)\}$ for starting values $\{H(0),h(0)\}=\{p,1-p\}$:

```
hd[p_, n_] := Nest[f, {p, 1 - p}, n];
```

Visualizing:

```
lp[p_] := 
 ListPlot[hdt[p, 10], Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 8}, 
  PlotLegends -> (Placed[
     SwatchLegend[Automatic, {"H(t)", "h(t)"}, 
      LegendLayout -> (Framed@Grid[#] &)], Scaled[{0.5, 0.5}]])];
Manipulate[lp[p], {p, 0.1, 0.9, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I know it doesn't answer your question directly, but with the definition above, your function `H[n]` asymptotically approaches 1 pretty fast regardless of the starting value `H[0]`:

```
(* Generates a table for the first 20 values of H given H[0] == alpha *)
f[alpha_] := Module[{H},
  H[0] = alpha;
  H[n_] := H[n] = H[n - 1] (1 + .7 (1 - H[n - 1]));
  Table[H[n], {n, 20}]]

ListLinePlot[Table[f[x], {x, 0, 1, .05}]]
```

produces

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could also do something like:

```
GraphicsRow[ListLinePlot@Transpose@RecurrenceTable[{
       H[n + 1] == N@(1 + (7 h[n])/10) H[n],
       h[n + 1] == N@1 - (1 + (7 h[n])/10) H[n], H[0] == #/100, 
       h[0] == 1/2},
      {H[n], h[n]}, {n, 1, 15}] & /@ {179, 180}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Note that `H + h == 1` as per the question, but you have `H[0]+h[0] != 1`, and also since these are frequencies, `H <= 1`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make my answer more comprehensible I decoupled the set of equations first:

```
(*1*) H[n+1]==7/10*H[n](17/7-H[n])
(*2*) h[n+1]==7/10*h[n](3/7+h[n])
```

with the constraints:

```
(h[n]+H[n]==1) && (0<=H[n]<=1) && (0<=h[n]<=1)
```

These can be obtained by using `h[n]+H[n]==1`. The recurence relations can now be solved independently. In this form it becomes clear, that the recurrence relations 1 and 2 are very similar to the logistic map.`RSolve` can find solutions of the logistic map for cases where an analytic solution exists (r=2 and r=4).

```
RSolve[a[n+1]==r(1-a[n])a[n]/.r->2,a[n],n]
```

Out:

```
{{a[n] -> 1/2 - 1/2 E^(2^n C[1])}}
```

Since there is no analytical solution available for aribtary `r`, Mathematica just gives back the expression (can be tested with `r->3` for example). The case of `H[n+1]==7/10(17/7-H[n])H[n]` is even more general, therefore there is probably no known analytic solution which could be given. Thus mathematica just returns the expression.

Regarding the fixed points of the system:
If one views the recurrence relations as functions and plots them,

```
Plot[{7/10 x (3/7 + x), 7/10 x (17/7 - x), x}, {x, 0, 1},PlotLegends->"Expressions"]
```

[image: convergence]

one can find the fixed points as the intersections with `f[x_]=x`. For any `1>H[0]>0` `H[n]` will converge towards `1` and `h[n]` will converge towards `0`. However `H[n]==0` and `h[n]==1` are also intersecting points obeying the constraints and thus a solution. With sligthly different parameters there will probably occure more complex behavior similar to the logistic map.

In case anyone spots an error please comment.